# Netbeans fails to compile JSP in projects created on different OS

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jenkins, operating-system

The next error occurs compiling a project in netbeans +7.2 when project has been created on different OS

```
compile-jsps:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/build/generated/src
     [java] Nov 05, 2013 4:47:29 PM org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner scanJar
     [java] WARNING: PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/ant.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/servlet3.1-jsp2.3-api.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/glassfish-jspparser-4.0.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/jstl-impl.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/javax.faces.jar does not exist
     [java] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/ant.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/servlet3.1-jsp2.3-api.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/glassfish-jspparser-4.0.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/jstl-impl.jar;/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/lib/jsp-compilation-syscp/javax.faces.jar (No such file or directory)
     [java]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
     [java]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
     [java]     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)
     [java]     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:89)
     [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
     [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
     [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:88)
     [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
     [java]     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJar(TldScanner.java:442)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:694)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:350)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.getLocation(TldScanner.java:283)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:500)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:582)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1657)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:185)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1171)
     [java]     at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1338)
     [java]     at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspC.main(JspC.java:101)
     [java] 
     [java] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/build/web/WEB-INF/auth.jsp(10,61) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem how to Netbeans call **JspC** apache compiler using **sysClasspath** argument. You can see mor info on netbeans [bug #198480](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198480)

Personally I would prefer changing build system to Maven, but it's a large and complicated project. Moreover I don't want to modify system generated files like **build-impl.xml**, so I prefer to wait something will broke (or fixed) with future NB updates and update properties files manually.

I search and improve the solution in this bug using custom build.xml modifications and not changing build-impl.xml. The next code solved my problem:

```
<!-- workaround bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198480 -->
<target name="checkos">
    <echo message="OS Name is:         ${os.name}"/>
    <echo message="OS Architecture is: ${os.arch}"/>
    <echo message="OS Version is:      ${os.version}"/>
    <condition property="is_windows">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="is_linux">
        <os family="unix"/>
    </condition>
</target>
<target name="patch-bug-198480-windows" if="is_windows" depends="checkos">
    <copy file="lib/nblibraries-syscp-windows.properties" tofile="lib/nblibraries-private.properties"/>
</target>
<target name="patch-bug-198480-linux" if="is_linux" depends="checkos">
    <copy file="lib/nblibraries-syscp-linux.properties" tofile="lib/nblibraries-private.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="-post-clean">
    <delete file="lib/nblibraries-private.properties"/>
</target>

    <target name="-pre-init" depends="patch-bug-198480-windows,patch-bug-198480-linux">
```

I take into account that libs.jsp-compilation-syscp.claspath are used only in two places in buidl-impl.xml and this modification don't changes behavior

File **nblibraries-syscp-linux.properties**

```
libs.jsp-compilation-syscp.classpath=\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/ant.jar:\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/servlet3.1-jsp2.3-api.jar:\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/glassfish-jspparser-4.0.jar:\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/jstl-impl.jar:\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/javax.faces.jar
libs.jsp-compilation-syscp.displayName=JSP Compilation Sysclasspath
```

File **nblibraries-syscp-windows.properties**

```
libs.jsp-compilation-syscp.classpath=\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/ant.jar;\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/servlet3.1-jsp2.3-api.jar;\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/glassfish-jspparser-4.0.jar;\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/jstl-impl.jar;\
    ${base}/jsp-compilation-syscp/javax.faces.jar
libs.jsp-compilation-syscp.displayName=JSP Compilation Sysclasspath
```

Important note: you should remember to update these files when NetBeans upgrades

Comment: Or you could migrate to another builder tool like maven.

Comment: Of course, but this isn't a trivial solution depending on the project. On the other hand, we plan to migrate to maven in a future. Thanks

Comment: Another solution would be just creating the project in your IDE using the sources of your project only. In this way, your Java code won't be affected by specific properties of IDE.

Comment: Sorry @Luiggy Mendoza but I don't undersand your last comment. I need to compile jsp and Netbeans uses this kind of proyect. Sure: we will migrate to maven soon.

Comment: I mean, you only keep the sources i.e. your packages with java code, JSPs, JS, CSS, image and other resources, and save these files only in a repository (using SVN, Git or other tool or even a simple folder created and maintained manually), then on each OS create a new project in your Netbeans (or other IDE) from these sources, so the projects share the same source but not the same IDE specific project properties like ant files.

Comment: To keep only the sources may be good enough, this is what I did, but the issue is on ant build system configured by netbeans, and I need this patch to allow a project generated in windows to be compiled and packaged by a Jenkins on linux. Finally, one year later from this question we migrated to maven. Anyway, thanks by your comments